# Proving a conditional $\forall \,n\in \Bbb Z : \left[P(n) \Rightarrow \lnot Q(n)\right]$ directly

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I want to give a direct proof of a conditionnal $$\forall\, n\in \Bbb Z : \left[ P(n) \Rightarrow \lnot Q(n) \right]$$ such that $$P(n)= n>2$$ and$$ Q(n)= \exists\ m \in \Bbb Z: (\,m+n=mn \wedge n|m\,)$$ hence, I want to prove that $$\forall\, n\in \Bbb Z : \left[\,n > 2 \Rightarrow  \lnot \exists\ m \in \Bbb Z: (\,m+n=mn \wedge n|m\,) \,\right] $$ is true.

I think that I proved the statement:

I take the converse, so $Q(n) \Rightarrow \lnot P(n)$ and assume $Q(n)$ hence, $n|m$.

It follows that $$m=nk: k\in\Bbb Z $$ Thus, $$k=\frac 1{n-1} \Rightarrow \left[m=\frac n{n-1}\in \Bbb Z \iff n=2\right] \Rightarrow \lnot P(n)$$

Therefore, $$\left[ Q(n) \Rightarrow \lnot P(n) \right]\Rightarrow \left[P(n) \Rightarrow \lnot Q(n)\right]$$ is true, by contrapositive.

What would be a direct proof of this statement? Is the contrapositive considered a form of direct proof?

Comment: @Matthew Leingang Thank you I edited my question, I think it is better now

Comment: Yes, that helps.  Note that statement $P$ is false, so $P\implies Q$ is true for all $Q$.

Comment: $Q$ has a free variable, namely $n$.

Comment: As noted, the statement $\forall n \in \Bbb Z : n > 2$ is false. Instead I think you mean to say, Let $n \in \Bbb Z$ with $n > 2$.

Comment: I suspect No Thought-No Concept is trying to prove $$\forall n\in \Bbb Z:\Big[ n>2 \implies \neg\exists m\in\Bbb Z:\big( m+n=mn ~\wedge~n\mid m\big)\Big]$$

Comment: @ajotatxe Is the free variable "hiding" in the fact that if $Q$ is true $n|m$? @ Graham Kemp Yes! that is what I want to prove thank you I shall edit my post!

Comment: If @GrahamKemp is right, then you can't split it up into $P$ and $Q$ that way.  Instead, the statement is of the form $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z} : [P(n) \implies \neg Q(n)]$, where $P(n)$ is $n>2$ and $Q(n)$ is $\exists m\in \mathbb{Z} : (m+n = mn \wedge n | m)$.

Comment: Could it be that a proof by contrapositive is the solution?

Comment: @user4894  Perhaps you've forgotten that, as Graham shows, $\forall n\in \mathbb Z\Big[n\gt 2 \rightarrow \lnot \exists m \in \mathbb Z((m+n = mn) \land (n\mid m))\Big]$.  Which means for every n that's an integer, **IF** $(n\gt 2)$, **then**....  The entire proposition says nothing about those $n$ such that $n\leq$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wish to prove the following statement.

For all integers $n$ such that $n > 2$, there does not exist an integer $m$ such that $m + n = mn$ and $n$ is divisible by $m$. We will prove this directly.

We first note that $mn = n + (m-1)n$. Therefore, $(m-1)n=m$ and $n = \frac {m}{m-1}$. I now cite some *previous knowledge* you may or may not know of. Two adjacent integers $a$ and $a+1$ do not share any prime factors. Therefore, $n = \frac {m}{m-1}$ is only true when $m-1$ has no prime factors to prevent the division from resulting in a whole number integer $n$. the only numbers with that quality are $-1$ and $1$. Therefore, $m$ can only be one of two values $m = 0$ or $m = 2$. This results in two values for $n$, which are $2$ and $0$.  Note that the only time $m$ exists satisfying the first condition is when the value for $n$ does not satisfy the given statement. Therefore, $m$ does not exist and the statement is true.

Comments/Note: I didn't use the divisibility portion of the statement. That's because I didn't need it. $n$ and $m$ are always equal by the equation and equal to either $2$ or $0$. I can only presume that the mention of divisibility is a red herring meant to throw off the op and make them think more critically about what is and is not useful in a proof.

Comment: I was thinking that I proved it by contrapositive if I assumed $Q$ and so if $n|m$ then, $m=nk\,:\,k \in \Bbb Z$ so we have $nk \,+\, n=n^2k$ which means $k=\frac 1{n-1}$ hence, $m=\frac n{n-1} \, \in \Bbb Z \iff n=2$ which means $\lnot P$. Therefore, since $Q \Rightarrow \lnot P$ we have $P \Rightarrow \lnot Q$ by contrapositive. I think your direct proof is more beautiful because of the argument you used though.

Comment: Should I always try to avoid referring to divisibility and simplify that kind of statement before I try to prove it or does that means taking the risk of loosing meaningful information?